# AWS API Gateway - returns 403 Forbidden on Express Proxy Middleware

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, react-apollo

I have an express server. I am trying to forward all requests to path `/grqphql` to an AWS gateway endpoint.

To achieve this I am using `express-http-proxy`

```
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

const app = express();
app.use('/graphql', proxy('https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql'));
```

The `/grapql` endpoint is called via a `apollo-graphql-client` on a react frontend. The POST grapql reqests returns a `Forbidden` error.

Few things to note.

- The lambda function is private (in a vpc)
- The api gateway is protected with a custom authorization function (checks Authorization header). But I am passing this header, this is not the problem.
- I have deployed api gateway in a 'dev' stage.

This is coming from AWS Gateway. The response has the header `x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException`. I have [reffered to the documentation regarding 403 errors](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/).  I suspect the issue is "Invoking a private API using public DNS names incorrectly" - in the linked documentaion.

Would appreciate some pointers on finding a workaround to this.

**Edit**:
Probably an issue with express-proxy middleware. As a woraround I've manually routed with axios. The following meets my requirments as this is a `graphql` endpoint.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': req.get('Authorization')
}
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: apiUrl,
    headers: headers,
    data: req.body
}).then((axiosResponse) => {
    res.status(axiosResponse.status).send(axiosResponse.data);
}).catch((error) => {
    res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.data);
});
```

Comment: Can you show the template that you're using to deploy your stack?

Comment: @Elbert I'm using serverless framework. And it is pretty big with lot of configuration. May I know what you are looking for in the temple?

Comment: The API Gateway output for the serverless API. When you set the resource, it will have a StageName property. I've run into this issue before where the StageName was not matching the URL being used in the request (e.g. case sensitivity). Cloudfront 403 is typically associated with an incorrect root path or failed authorization with the `x-api-key` header. Seeing as you're getting an error back, I am assuming the VPC is configured correctly because if I remember, misconfiguration often results in a timeout.

Comment: Yes, I've looked into this (based on similar stackoverflow questions). The api is deployed with a stage name of 'dev', and that is added to endpoint url correctly. `'https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/graphql`

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of the serverless template's API Gateway (or Serverless Api), and the lambda resource?

Comment: I've found a workaround. Please see my edit in the question. Looks like it is a problem with express-proxy middleware. Not sure tho. Thank you for loooking at this Elbert.

Comment: That's great. I suspect the headers might be the problem. If you want to investigate further, you can log the `headers` using `userResHeaderDecorator` in the proxy option callback and see if it's what you expect it to be.